# Callkit With Regular Call

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

Can Callkit be used to detect incoming calls? I mean regular GSM calls, not voip, if not, is there a way to detect call events on ios? I want to show a notification on an incoming call, and I need to detect the call event if my app is in background/terminated.

Comment: No, there is no background notification when an incoming call is received.

Comment: in android, there are broadcast receivers that you can listen to and run a service when a broadcast received, such as a phone call broadcast. I am not sure about the terms for iOS, is there something equivalent?

Comment: bottom line, I want to show a dialog/pop up/ notification when someone is calling, is this achievable for iOS?

Comment: No. The system shows the incoming call notification.  Apps cannot. If you want to display a caller name you can provide numbers and names to iOS via a callkit identification extension.